# RockyLinux: unable to load cifs module

Tags: cifs, kernel-modules, rocky-linux

I have installed RockyLinux 8.5 and am trying to mount a directory via cifs. I get the following error message:

```sh
# mount -t cifs -o user=<remarked>,domain=<remarked>,password=<remarked> //<remarked>/backups /mnt/backups
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system 
mount error(19): No such device 
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

The RPM packages `cifs-utils` and `samba-utils` are booth installed, but it seems to be, that the kernel can not find the `cifs` module because it is not possible to load it:

```sh
# find / -name "cifs"
/usr/lib/modules/4.18.0-348.el8.0.2.x86_64/kernel/fs/cifs
# lsmod | grep cifs
# modprobe cifs
modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-348.el8.0.2.x86_64
```

Does anyone have an idea why RockyLinux cannot load the `cifs` module? This is probably the problem why the mount does not work.

Here are additionally my [dmesg logs](https://pastebin.com/16kw5vua). I cant found anything about cifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. I've installed such a minimal version of RockyLinux, that the RPM `kernel-modules` and `kernel-core` were missing.

After installing booth RPMs could `cifs` be loaded via `modprobe cifs`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have the cifs module, else you would have seen

```
# find / -name "cifs"
/usr/lib/modules/4.18.0-348.el8.0.2.x86_64/kernel/fs/cifs
/usr/lib/modules/4.18.0-348.el8.0.2.x86_64/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
```

Comment: The `find` command found cifs here: `/usr/lib/modules/4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64/kernel/fs/cifs` (and `cifs.ko.xz`) how do I load that ? `modprobe cifs` says `Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.0` but that directory does not even exist, it is `/usr/lib` instead.